# Inappropriate phrase in the moderator message templates

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

Can we have the phrase:

> This is a troubling pattern and has become abusive to our community

removed from the low quality contributions moderator message template or at least reworded?

I try to remove this from the messages I send (but I don't always remember) as I find this part of the message almost embarrassing to send. You can't abuse a community only its members, and it's a little over the top.

Comment: What? Who? When? Where? I've never seen this message before (Mod only supapowa?)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha The only way you'd see this would be if you were at the receiving end of a mod message/suspension.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - yes it's a diamond moderator thing. Hence the [tag:moderator-tools] tag: "Tools available to ♦ moderators."

Comment: @MadaraUchiha unlike many other places (aka forums) moderators here don't have private forum, so it's not uncommon to see moderators only discussions like this. (There is chat of course, but I guess that unless it's something private or sensitive, they prefer discussing everything here on Meta)

Comment: Meh, why can't you be abusive to a community? You can be abusive to a person or multiple people, a community is just a plurality of people. Ergo you can abuse a community. Perhaps more accurately they're abusing the *site*, but the more important thing is that the *community* has to put up with their crap.

Answer (score 8):

As [Ben Brocka](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/166936/ben-brocka) said, *community* is a term used to mean a group of people. You can be abusive to a community, if what you do involves one, or more members of a community.

I agree with [Thomas Owens](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/572/thomas-owens) when he says you should always edit the template to adapt it; at least, you should check the text is appropriate for the specific case. The template is a static text, generic enough to be useful in most of the cases. I find preferable the text used for the message contains a phrase I delete, rather than remembering to add a phrase.

I don't have data about how much times I would remove that phrase, but I think it is true in most of the cases, when the user needs to be suspended. If the user needs to be suspended, s/he surely has been abusive to the community, in some way.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with this.

This is overly stern, akin to a mother scolding a child for bad behavior.  Most people would take offense to it and it will have the opposite effect to what we desire, to help people understand the rules and become better members of the community.

Answer (score 3):

I think most, if not all, of the moderator messages are generally inappropriate without significant edits.

For example, the default low quality questions post mentions things that have nothing to do with low quality questions. For example, it suggests answering questions. Yes, it's good to answer questions and help other people solve their problems, but not answering questions is not something that will solve low quality questions. Another example is that it mentions reading the markdown help - there's a difference between vague or non-constructive questions and poorly formatted questions.

Comment: "answer questions" to remove Q ban, probably applicable in some cases, easy to delete, annoying to type. "Markdown Help" has been applicable in multiple messages I have sent, but as with all of them, it is much faster to delete a couple then it is to retype them. If they are common it is worth having.